# How to get XML Attributes with XPath in JSDOM

Tags: javascript, node.js, xml, xpath, jsdom

I can't seem to be able to get XML Attributes using JSDOM and XPath Syntax on this XML Snippet.

```xml
<PARAGRAPH>
    This is a text, about something, that happened on 
    <DATE ISO="20131117">17.November 2013</DATE>
    . It is a very important date.
</PARAGRAPH>
```

By my understanding `PARAGRAPH/DATE/@ISO` is valid XPath Syntax for the Attribute and it's working just fine on sites like [Xpather](http://xpather.com/)

**Minimal working example:**

```js
import { JSDOM } from "jsdom";

const xml = `
<PARAGRAPH>
    This is a text, about something, that happened on 
    <DATE ISO="20131117">17.November 2013</DATE>
    . It is a very important date.
</PARAGRAPH>
`;

const dom = new JSDOM(xml, {contentType: "application/xml"});
const doc = dom.window.document;

// 2: XPathResult.STRING_TYPE
const date = doc.evaluate("PARAGRAPH/DATE/@ISO", doc, null, 2, null).stringValue;

console.log(date);
```

**Expected Result:** `"20131117"`

**Actual Result:** `""`

**Other non-working approaches**

`PARAGRAPH//DATE/@ISO`,
`string(PARAGRAPH/DATE/@ISO)`, `XPath.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE`

The evaluation seems to come back empty.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps try

```
const dateEl = doc.evaluate("PARAGRAPH/DATE", doc, null, 9, null).singleNodeValue;

const date = dateEl.getAttribute("ISO");
```

Comment: Since I'm using TS - getAttribute is not defined on Type Node in nodejs/JSDOM.
I'm using `dateEl["getAttribute"]("ISO")` right now, but it's not very elegant to call the function outside of the `JSDOM.Node` Type.

Comment: If you want to get that library fixed try to raise an issue on their Github site. I suggested the above as a workaround to somehow get at the attribute, even if direct XPath selection for some reasons doesn't appear to work. As for the type problem, I don't know TypeScript well, isn't there a way to cast the `dateEl` to the DOM `Element` type/interface (where the `getAttribute` method should be exposed)?

Comment: I opened an issue for the original problem and the implementation of XPath @Attr. https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/issues/3293

You could add the signature by casting:
`(dateEl as Node & Element).getAttribute("")`

Answer (score 0):

try this with camaro. test with runkit here https://runkit.com/embed/vxenbgqb1g7x

```js
var { transform } = require("camaro")

var xml = `
<PARAGRAPH>
    This is a text, about something, that happened on 
    <DATE ISO="20131117">17.November 2013</DATE>
    . It is a very important date.
</PARAGRAPH>
`;

async function main() {
    console.log(await transform(xml, {iso: 'PARAGRAPH/DATE/@ISO'}))
}

main()
```

output

```
{iso: "20131117"}
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, lowercasing the `iso=` attribute seems to work with your original code:

```js
import {JSDOM} from "jsdom"; // ^24.0.0

const xml = `
<PARAGRAPH>
    This is a text, about something, that happened on
    <DATE iso="20131117">17.November 2013</DATE>
    . It is a very important date.
</PARAGRAPH>
`;

const dom = new JSDOM(xml, {contentType: "application/xml"});
const doc = dom.window.document;

// 2: XPathResult.STRING_TYPE
const date = doc.evaluate("PARAGRAPH/DATE/@ISO", doc, null, 2, null).stringValue;
console.log(date); // => 20131117
```

If you can't change the input string, here are some workarounds:

1. Remove `{contentType: "application/xml"}` and query from `//`:

   ```js
   const dom = new JSDOM(xml);
   const doc = dom.window.document;

   // 2: XPathResult.STRING_TYPE
   const date = doc
     .evaluate("//PARAGRAPH/DATE/@ISO", doc, null, 2, null)
     .stringValue;
   console.log(date); // => 20131117
   ```
2. Use CSS queries:

   ```js
   const dom = new JSDOM(xml, {contentType: "application/xml"});
   const doc = dom.window.document;
   const date = doc.querySelector("DATE").getAttribute("ISO");
   console.log(date); // => 20131117
   ```
3. Use Cheerio:

   ```js
   import cheerio from "cheerio"; // ^1.0.0-rc.12

   const xml = `
   <PARAGRAPH>
       This is a text, about something, that happened on
       <DATE ISO="20131117">17.November 2013</DATE>
       . It is a very important date.
   </PARAGRAPH>
   `;

   console.log(cheerio.load(xml, {xml: true})("DATE").attr("ISO"));

   // or:
   console.log(cheerio.load(xml)("date").attr("iso"));
   ```

---

I noticed after posting that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70065663/6243352) works as well, but I'll leave this around for completeness.